# How to improve this design?

Tags: website-design

How can I improve this design? I'm kinda new to this and I've just felt a bit demotivated because I've been dealing with a difficult person.

I intend to make the color of the copyright notice darker and add padding around the logo.
I'm not sure about the blue sidebar on the left, but I was asked to make it similar to cia.gov website in terms of the color and side menu. I was also asked to add flickering star animation to the logo. I'm not too keen on the idea, I think it's a bit cheesy.

[Link](http://blackhut.co.za/#)

Thanks!!!!

Comment: "Add flickering star animation to the logo"? Just fire the client now and save yourself the acida. Seriously.

Comment: I don't want to demotivate you even further, but this isn't a question that fits our format. It's asking for a discussion. Try to narrow it down (see the FAQ for guidance) to something that can be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, the good news is the design is clean and fairly easy to read.

• As a designer you need to hold your ground. Adding a flickering star animation will only cheapen the logo. Ask them for a reference to any other well known logo that features an animation to their logo on their website.

• If anything the current logo needs to be cleaned up. The design and images used on the site are crisp and clean. Yet, the Mustang Group Holdings logo is blurry, muddy, using too many gradients in the images and text and DOESN'T need a drop shadow. I would do the mustang in a solid color (blue or black) and again a solid color on the name. NO DROP SHADOW.

• Why the difference in the main image/quick links/our brands? I would think a larger image that shuffles through that showcases all would work better. Also don't like how you have two sections of shuffling images. Too much is going on. One section featuring shuffling images should be plenty.

• It seems like a pretty small website. If that's the case I don't think you'll need a search box.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion about the content architecture ( arranging content ),and I  think it's better if you limit your text areas  to an Html fonts (Verdan, Calbri, Arail...etc). Check this:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post links using URL shorteners.  If you have an image you would like to post, please include the full URL in your post.  After you you build up some [rep](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq), you'll be able to post images.